# Como puedo generar un script para MySQL a partir del siguiente modelo Entidad- Relacion?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo que generar una base de datos a partir del modelo entidad relacion pero no entiendo de donde vienen los index que están en la tabla Modulo_Alumno por eso quisiera saber como puedo crear cada una de las tablas del modelo con sus ***Primary Keys*** en lenguaje *SQL*, recientemente empecé en la programación por eso no conozco mucho, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.  [image: Modelo Entidad Relacion]

Comment: Y el modelo que estás mostrando solamente lo tienes en imagen?

Comment: Si únicamente en imagen lo tengo

Comment: Mírate el manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html, intenta algo, comparte los errores o dificultades que te encuentres y será un placer ayudarte...

Comment: Como dice @david-jp debes leer sobre el tema y tratar de generar un código y sobre eso se te puede ayudar.